# South Korea defeated Germany who defeated Sweden who defeated Mexico who defeated South Korea

Tags: football, world-cup

In the 2018 World Cup group F, South Korea defeated Germany who defeated Sweden who defeated Mexico who defeated South Korea and thereby took the most indirect revenge.

Did such a long circular chain of defeats ever happened in any of the previous world cups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the 1994 FIFA World Cup, Mexico beat the Republic of Ireland (2-1), that had beaten Italy (0-1), that had beaten Norway (1-0), that had beaten Mexico (1-0). All of this happened in [Group E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_E), which is also the only group in the history o the World Cup in which ***all*** teams ended with the same number of points (4) and the same goal difference (0).

Comment: I still remember that group, even though I was a boy back then.. But didn't know it had a similar chain...